# GNU plot complains about bad timing format, the format seems correct

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot some data using gnuplot, more specifically pidstat commands that looks like this one below

```
#      Time       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s  Command
 06:47:54 pm        12    0.04    0.19    0.00    0.24     2     21.50      0.03   26944   2768   0.07     -1.00     -1.00     -1.00  nginx
 06:47:55 pm        12    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.03     0      0.00      0.00       0      0   0.00     -1.00     -1.00     -1.00  nginx
 06:47:56 pm        12    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0      0.00      0.00       0      0   0.00     -1.00     -1.00     -1.00  nginx
 06:47:57 pm        12    0.00    0.08    0.00    0.08     2      0.00      0.00       0      0   0.00     -1.00     -1.00     -1.00  nginx
 06:47:58 pm        12    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.03     1      0.00      0.00       0      0   0.00     -1.00     -1.00     -1.00  nginx
 06:47:59 pm        12    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     1      0.00      0.00       0      0   0.00     -1.00     -1.00     -1.00  nginx
 06:48:00 pm        12    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.01     2      0.00      0.00       0      0   0.00     -1.00     -1.00     -1.00  nginx
```

Im using this script

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%I:%M:%S %p"
plot "pid_output.log" using 1:4 with lines title "%usr", \
     "pid_output.log" using 1:14 with lines title "%MEM"
```

However Im getting the same error no matter what I do

`"gnu_plot_script.gp" line 14: warning: Bad time format in string`

Any recommendation or obvious error Im having? I have cleaned the output a bit. the pid command im ussing to generate the output is the following if you want to try.

`pidstat -urd -h -p <pid> 1 10 > pidstat_output.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timefmt` doesn't understand `%I`, you have to use `%H` instead. Interestingly, `%I` can be used in `set xtics format`.

Comment: Good to know. From the documentation `help time_specifiers` it's not clear that `%I` apparently is only for output. Probably the same for`%l`.